# Why are my comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I recently flagged 19 comments as too chatty or obsolete and have had all of them declined.

The comments were of the following nature:

- > +1 for the explanation.
- > I guess you mean the shift key? Also, link-only answers are not very helpful if the link ever stops working!
  > @LarsEbert OMG what a spell error :)
  > Much better now +1
- > Thank you, finally the problem is solved.
  > +1. Excellent answer!

Why were these comment flags declined? The comments are completely superfluous and as comments are ephemeral why should these comments not be removed?

My post flag accuracy is over 98% with almost 1500 flags, but my comment flag accuracy is only 35% with only 80 flags.

Why are my comment flags declined? At one point, I had a few flags declined for comments on the same post, which were then removed anyway later.

Comment: I had the same issue in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390290/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-imacs-internal-drive-disappear-completely-without-rem/390316#390316), where the users go into discussing how to edit/use StackExchange. When flagging for chatty, they just got declined.

Comment: @Efren Not all flags are declined for the same reasons. If you want to discuss why some recent flags of yours got declined please ask a new question here on Meta (and add a link to the post you've flagged for reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily because I didn't pay attention and hit the "dismiss" link instead of the "delete" link. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems flags can not re-flagged, given this check

`You have already raised this type of flag and can no longer reraise it`

So users who accidentally "dismiss" flags should be deleting the comments when flagging was legitimate.