# Why are comment flags declined if comments are obsolete and the obsolete flag was used?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

Similar to this [question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2433/35933) I had the same issue in [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390316/35933), where the users go into discussing how to edit/use StackExchange. When flagging for chatty, they just got declined.

Example comments:

- > that should be in the question - I didn't see it under the rolled up comments - and it completely changes the context of the OPs original post. Do you have edit privilege yet? If so, edit it and get the credit for the fix as well.
- > @Allan Agreed. I am unable and unfamiliar with editing an original question. It should be suggested to OP, I assume. (And, I also don't like the rolling up of comments.)

Got several flags rejected without reason, when the comments are clearly about using StackExchange, and also have the edits were done so reading those comments is just a waste of time.

Comment: How did it workout for you @grg? Did you manage to improve a question by cleaning up obsolete comments or did you also find rejections blocking you?

Answer (score 3):

Comment flags can only be acted upon (resulting in the deletion of the comment) or declined, there is no option to provide feedback (which is actually optional also for flags on post).

I didn't handle the flags on these comments, but I would have declined them as well. The comments show good community actions on helping a new user to understand the site better and to collaboratively improve the quality of a post. So it is a good example for future visitors to better understand how the site works and how everybody can help to improve it.

PS: As a side remark: It's usually enough to flag *one* comment beneath a post. We usually look at the comment in context when handling the flag anyway.

Comment: The comments are still obsolete and confusing to people reading the Q&A since the edits have been done already. Isn't the point of comments to add value or information on the actual topic? Also, isn't cleaning up obsolete comments part of improving the site? Otherwise, what's the point of that flag? I see on your other answer that comments like the ones I flagged, you agreed on declining, so it's really confusing to what are the goals of good community actions.

Comment: Also I only flagged the related obsolete comments to make it easier to cleanup. Having all flags rejected looks more like the user didn't even want. to look at the context.

Comment: @Efren "+1. Excellent answer!" comments are always candidates for deletion, they do not add any value to the vote given.

Comment: In StackOverflow, discussions in comments are also taken to the chat, rather than populating the Q&A with comments that are not related to the OP, is this not the intention in Apple.StackExchange?

Comment: can you agree on what is for deletion and what is not? In this answer you say "I would have declined them as well", yet in the comment you say "candidates for deletion, they do not add any value to the vote given"

Comment: @Efren Moving to chat is an option as well, and something we use sometimes. Handling of comments is different on the various SE sites. SO gets much more comments than we do, so I understand why they are more focused on deleting them.

Comment: @efren The answer was referring to your comments on the answer on main, the remark in the comment was referring to "+1. Excellent answer!" comments.

Comment: I still don't see what value they add to the OP, how about the other comments you agreed to delete in the other [question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2434/35933) how do you determine then if value is added? - PS: if this site works different to SO, then you haven't answered "what's the point of that flag?"

Comment: @efren The comments on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390316/35933 add value to the site as a whole.

Comment: @efren Also, if you think a *post* needs improving, editing it is usually the better approach than flagging. Just make sure the edits are substantial.

Comment: I second the “one flag per question” guidance, that way you don’t get a raft of declined comments if some portion of one of the comments appears to be helpful. Keep in mind, the system rolls up long comments automagically, so people don’t see all the comments - just the top ones.